# addClass/removeClass are not working properly

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

I have 5 button each of them have the class .leg, I want when the user clicks on one of them to add 'active' on the class attribute and remove it from every other, so I have:

```
j$(".leg").on "click", (event)->
  j$('.leg').removeClass('active')
  j$(event.target).addClass('active')
```

Sometimes when I click on one of the button the 'active' class is not added. I suspect that the removeClass has not finish its execution, 'active' is added and then removed again. Since the `removeClass` does not have a callback is there any other way to fix this issue?

http://jsfiddle.net/k4605e3z/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$(this)` instead of `$(e.target)`:

```
$('.leg').click(function(event){
  $('.leg').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

`this` is the dom element selected when you added the click handler.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/k4605e3z/1/)

Comment: works perfectly, I will accept your answer because you were the first. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Simply change this :

```
$('.leg').click(function(event){
    $('.leg').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an element inside `.leg` so when you click, the target is the `span`. You can get the parent by this  `event.target.parentElement`

```
$('.leg').click(function(event){
  $('.leg').removeClass('active');
  $(event.target.parentElement).addClass('active')
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/k4605e3z/2/)